# Vue.js 2.0: ES6 export from main.js (webpack entry point)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, vue.js

I'm using the [webpack-simple-2.0 template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple-2.0) for Vue.js (2.0.0-beta.5).

If I add `export const FOO='bar'` inside my `main.js`, I'm unable to `import { FOO } from 'main.js'` inside another .js file of mine, it results in `undefined`. It works fine if I put that `export` inside any other .js file other than `main.js`

`main.js` is where Vue gets set up and it's also webpack's entry point. Does this limit what I can export from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think webpack won't allow exporting a value from the entrypoint.

This is how I handle the problem:

I create a `bootstrap.js` to configure the application and export what I need to use later.
In `main.js` I require `bootstrap.js` and initialize my Vue-instance.

`main.js`:
https://github.com/petervmeijgaard/vue-2.0-boilerplate/blob/master/src/main.js

`bootstrap.js`:
https://github.com/petervmeijgaard/vue-2.0-boilerplate/blob/master/src/bootstrap.js